# c# console app will not run as a scheduled task on specific server

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, console-application

I have a console application that performs some data work and then closes.  If I run the executable manually it opens a command prompt, runs the program, and closes.  No issues at all regardless of what Microsoft OS I'm using.

However, if I attempt to run the program as a scheduled task it fails on one specific server running Windows Server 2008 R2.  It works as a scheduled task just fine on other servers, including another Windows Server 2008 R2 box in the same building.  Unfortunately this one server is the server it needs to run on.  I've tried adding logging, writing to the event logs, executing the application as an administration, forcing 32 or 64 bit, and launching it as a separate launch from a .bat file.  Nothing.  The program isn't crashing, it is just never opening.

Does anyone know what may be causing this?  I'm at a loss and I don't know what to do.

Edit:  I created a test .bat file that just launches a command prompt to see if it would open a command prompt window.  It does not.  The other tasks seem to run fine though.

Edit #2:  I have been researched this and something that has come up is to set the task to enable with desktop.  I can't find that option nor can I think of a reason why it would fix this issue but it seems to keep coming up.

Comment: Do other scheduled tasked work on the box?

Comment: Do you have the option 'Run whether user is logged on or not' checked.

Comment: @SamLeach - Yes, other tasks seem to run fine.

Comment: @roughnex - I have that box checked.

Comment: Does the admin account have a password? I would try a blank/simple C# app if it does, does that work?

Comment: @SamLeach - It does have an admin account and the password is being specified.  I will try a simple c# app and report back.

Comment: @SamLeach - I tried a simple c# console app and the program seemed to execute but it would not open a command prompt.  I set it to remain open until the user types 'QUIT' but I could see the active process in the task manager.  When I run the main application I don't ever see it show up in the task manager.  What is different about the way a scheduled task executes as opposed to just launching an application?

Comment: I don't know. I've had troubles with scheduled tasks in the past though. Please reply if you figure it out!

Comment: If you run the schedule task under the credentials under which it successfully runs on the console, does it run? Can you run that task in a command window on the specific machine? IF not, what errors do you see? When was the last time that machine was rebooted?

Comment: @NicholasCarey - 1.  No, it will not run as a scheduled task.  2.  Yes, I can.  It will run fine from the command window.  3.  I do not know when it was last rebooted.  I'm not sure I'll be allowed to reboot it either.  I will check.

Comment: Look at the event log for any error, warning or critical event. Even if it does not immediately appear to relate to your scheduled task, it might give insight as to another component that is preventing your desired behavior.

Answer (score 7):

After a bit of fiddling around this is what worked for me. When you point to the console application in the actions Tab, ensure that you fill in the 'Start in' field with the location where the executable is located even though it says that it is optional. Once you fill that in, it will work.

Comment: you save my life! I search for the issue in half day